# Can C# Aforge.net running on a Raspberry PI

Tags: c#, python, mongodb, aforge

I'm going to develop a software which needs to be run on a Raspberry PI.there basically i had to do image processing,and need to implement a neural network too. and environmental factors took by sensor reading(humidity,temperature and sunlight) are needs to be input to the neural network to train it. This is a simple description of the project that i'm going to do.
For that i'm going to use mongo db for back end, and C# AForge.net for image processing and neural network implementations.

Can someone explain me is it good to use C#, with mongo db for this purpose.and most importantly this application should run on raspberry pi,So for these tasks What is the language that better to use C# with mongo db or Python with mongo db.
I'm a complete beginner to these languages but i had little bit experience in C#,and the time limit also very critical factor in our project, So what will be the best technology to learn and easy to use in these circumstances. Is it C# Aforge.net with mongo db or python with mongo db?

Please can someone explain me? 
Thanks in Advance!!!